# XML parsing with namespaces

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have this sample code which parses XML weather data from yahoo, what I have to do it simplify it somehow, and possibly make it in a loop, but I can't figure out how. The XML have namespaces and that's part of the problem, here is what I have so far:

```java
private MyWeather parseWeather(Document doc) {

        MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();
        myWeather.description = doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
        Node locationNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location").item(0);
        myWeather.city = locationNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("city").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.region = locationNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("region").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.country = locationNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("country").getNodeValue().toString();
        Node windNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:wind").item(0);
        myWeather.windChill = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("chill").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.windDirection = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("direction").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.windSpeed = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed").getNodeValue().toString();
        Node astronomyNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:astronomy").item(0);
        myWeather.sunrise = astronomyNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("sunrise").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.sunset = astronomyNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("sunset").getNodeValue().toString();
        Node conditionNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
        myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().toString();
        myWeather.conditiondate = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue().toString();

        return myWeather;
    }
```

and on MyWeather class I have this

```java
public class MyWeather {
    public String description;
    public String city;
    public String region;
    public String country;
    public String windChill;
    public String windDirection;
    public String windSpeed;
    public String sunrise;
    public String sunset;
    public String conditiontext;
    public String conditiondate;

    public String toString() {

        return "\n- " + description + " -\n\n" + "city: " + city + "\n" + "region: " + region + "\n" + "country: " + country + "\n\n"

        + "Wind\n" + "chill: " + windChill + "\n" + "direction: " + windDirection + "\n" + "speed: " + windSpeed + "\n\n"

        + "Sunrise: " + sunrise + "\n" + "Sunset: " + sunset + "\n\n"

        + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n" + conditiondate + "\n";

    }
}
```

the link I am parsing from is this - http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=838804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of [getElementsByTagName](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)